Uncaught error after using Express's res.redirect
I am trying to redirect the user to the home page after registering (which includes automatic login). However, I keep getting this error. I have no idea why this is happening, and I've been trying to fix it for two days. Your help will be greatly appeciate! :')

Error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Relevant code (i think):
// BACKEND registerController.ts

res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')

.
// FRONTEND apiHandler.ts

const init = {
    method,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
};

const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api${endpoint}`, init);


obviously your client is expecting some JSON response, but the backend is sending some html. Use the browsers developer tools to check what the backend actually returns.  This often happens when some error happens in the backend and the server returns an error document, for exampe for 404 not found ...

@derpirscher yes, but why is that? from what I have read and saw in youtube res.redirect should redirect your client URL to the specified url directly... however, my client is expecting JSON and the backend is sending an HTML?

impossible to say from that little code you show. Have a look at the browser's developer tools and check, what the request is, what its statuscode is and then check what that request is doing on the backend ...  We also don't see what you are doing with this response object. But when you redirect to http://localhost:3000 (ie the root) it's pretty much expected, that the server would return a index.hml or similar ...
